# sql server varbinay(max) truncated error

Tags: c#, sql-server, varbinary

I have a table with a column of type varbinary(max) to which i'm trying to update with a byte array.  i think i'm doing it correctly with the code below, but i always get the "data will be truncated" error.  info.logoBin is the byte[] and its size is about 200k (it's an image file).

```
using (SqlConnection conn = OpenConnection())
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE COMPANIES SET LOGO_TYPE=@param1, LOGO_HASH=@param2, " +
            "LOGO_BIN=@param3 WHERE ID=@param4";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", info.LogoType);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", info.LogoHash);
        if (info.LogoBin != null)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@param3", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = info.LogoBin;
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@param3", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);
            cmd.Parameters["@param3"].Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param4", id);

        ExecNonQuery(cmd);
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

I've tried specifying a size, i've tried using SqlDbType.Image, i've even tried just giving the value new byte[] { 0xff, 0xfa }, but i always get the same error.  last, i tried the following  in sql server mgmt server and it worked fine:

```
insert into COMPANIES (LOGO_BIN) values (0xfffa);
```

by the way I'm using vs 2008 pro and sql server 2012  express.  any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't on the LOGO_TYPE or LOGO_HASH columns? Also, is there a trigger on the companies table?

Comment: of course i was sure, and of course i was wrong :)  how embarassing.  if you answer it, i'll approve.

Comment: in case anybody is wondering, this method works as-is.  my logo_hash column was a varchar(32), but c# adds dashes to MD5.ToString() so it should have been varchar(48).